# How do you describe a study which attempts to isolate the compounding effect of factor A on factor B?

Tags: academia, phrasing

Shameless cry for academic help here.

I'm working on my thesis, which is a study that will focus on the compounding effect of group dynamics on persuasive technology. The control and treatment group will be given daily SMS notifications encouraging them to walk, but the control group will be participating as disparate individuals, and the treatment group will be a group working in the same office together. The dependent variable is their weekly step count over the course of the month. I just need some help on the title. Does this imply that I am attempting to isolate the effects of group dynamics and the effects of SMS notifications/triggers and report on each? or does this imply that I am only going to study the compounding effect of group dynamics on what we already understand are the overall effects of mobile notifications?

`The Compounding Effects of Interoffice Group Dynamics and
SMS Behavioral Triggers on the Ambulation of Utah Tech Professionals`

I would need to have four groups (group w/ SMS, group w/o SMS, individuals w/ SMS, individuals w/o SMS) if I wanted to tease out the impact of triggers vs group dynamics. I'm trying to make it clear that I'm not doing that.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I don't think this is an issue of English expression so much as (a) you achieving clarity on exactly what it is you're testing, and (b) your assessor's preference for how a thesis is to be titled (e.g., is a description of the subject cohort – "Utah Tech Professionals" – required?). Have you sought guidance from your supervisor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the title is adequate as it stands. The goal is to describe the task without the title becoming as large as the abstract. You may clarify your intentions with one of the following;

Study of A depending on B with/without regard to the effects of C.

or

Study of A depending on B exclusive of the effects of C.

or

Study of A depending on B as viewed through the occurrence/presence of C.